# Residue theorem for a rational integral

Tags: complex-numbers

given the integral

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}dx \frac{x^{s}}{Q(x)} = \oint _{C} dz \frac{z^{s}}{Q(z)} $$

here 's' is a parameter , this can be real or complex so there is a branch cut

'C encloses ALL the Zeros of  $ Q(x) $

my question is for any given Q(X) how can ia pply cauchy theorem, (including the branch point) to obtain the integral ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know little about $Q$, I will assume it and $s$ are such that the integral converges.  Let the zeroes of $Q$ be $z_k$, $k \in \{1,2,\ldots,N\}$.  I also assume that $Q(0)=1$.  It can be shown with a keyhole-shaped contour about the positive real axis that

$$\left (1-e^{i 2 \pi s}\right ) \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x^s}{Q(x)} = i 2 \pi \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{z_k^s}{Q'(z_k)}$$

so long as $s \notin \mathbb{Z}$. Note that I assumed a branch cut along the positive real axis.

There are special cases of $Q$ in which a wedge-shaped contour rather than a keyhole contour may be used.  The wedge angle is chosen such that $Q$ is invariant to a rotation in that angle in the complex plane.  The advantage of using a wedge is that you can ignore the poles outside the wedge, making the calculation easier.